# Is the ExtLib Modal dialog responsive?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

The custom control 'dialog' from the ExtLib is not responsive. The value inside is responsive, but the dialog itself not.
What I am doing wrong? Or is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, now I have the solution.
I have insert a fixed width. Now I have insert percent value and it is responsive.
Bad fail from me.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see this post by Johnny Oldenburger for another way to do dialogs that would be responsive http://xpagesandmore.blogspot.nl/2015/05/bootstrap-js-modal-plugin-in-xpages.html

Comment: The post is good. But what is with the custom control 'dialog'? Do I need to build my own dialogue as Jonny Oldenburger makes it?

Comment: Probably to be responsive...are you using version 12 of the Ext Lib from OpenNTF? That added some new responsive features but I am not sure they have made the dialog responsive. Might be a good idea to post that question in the discussions for the Ext Lib project.

Comment: I use version 12 of the Ext Lib. I try it on a other way.